# Am I handling this Rails Form Correctly?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, view, controllers

In my relationships_controller I have the following:

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user_id = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
    @relationship = Relationship.new
  end

  def create
    @relationship = Relationship.new(params[:relationship])
    @relationship.rel_id = User.find_by_id(params[:user_id])
    @relationship.user_id = current_user
    if @relationship.save
        redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed Up!"
    else
        render "new"
    end
  end
end
```

and in my views I have:

```
<section id="main">
  <%= form_for [@user_id, @relationship]  do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :type %>
      <%= select_tag(:type, options_for_select([['Friend', 0], ['Family', 1],['Spouse', 2]])) %>
    </div>
   <div class="actions"><%= f.submit %></div>
  <% end %>
</section>
```

I have a few questions:

1. Is this the correct way to handle the rel_id and the user_id? It seems kinda clunky to me.
2. I can't get the :type to save to the database, but everything else does. I find the following in my server logs:

`Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"z7R4tWSSVHZmFXfh8HocfyuegZ2rwuXXeTLKbR+cLfs=", "type"=>"0", "commit"=>"Create Relationship", "user_id"=>"7"}`

which seems odd to me because it should be saving type.

3.. Does it matter if I use @user_id or @current user in the `<%= form_for [@user_id, @relationship]  do |f| %>` line? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `@user_id` is actually assigned an instance of `User`, so I would call it `@user`
when assigning `rel_id` I think you just need the user id value (integer).  You can probably just do this:

```
@relationship.rel_id = params[:user_id]
```

2) `type` fields are used for STI tables with ActiveRecord, and bad things happen if you name your field `type` for any other reason.  Try changing it to another name like `relationship_type`

3) Possible, depending on how your app is set up.  It's possible that @user(_id) and @current_user represent different users.  If you only want the current user to create a relationship for himself/herself, then you can just use @current_user (and maybe not use nested routes in that case).

Comment: `@user` is the person `@current_user` is friending. They should always be different users. I haven't coded that check in yet.

Comment: I watched Railscast #139 on Nesting Comments and the suggestions there make me think that nesting this is appropriate. Is there any reason why you believe otherwise?

Comment: In that case nested resources are fine.  I was just a bit unsure of how you wanted to user @user compared to current_user.

Comment: current_user is a method that determines who is logged in. So in this case the current_user is logged in and is establishing a relationship with `@user`. Does that make sense? I believe this is what my code is doing, but I still am not getting relationship_type saved for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

Calling an attribute "type" is a no-no in rails, because it already defines a type method on your classes that inherit from ActiveRecord::Base. It is used for single-table-inheritance.

The least painful thing would be to rename that column to "relationship_type" or "kind", but you can get around it like this if you really need to:

```
@relationship = Relationship.new(params[:relationship])
@relationship[:type] = params[:type]
```

Comment: I took the less painful route, but it still isn't saving. I would have expected it to complain about :type before if it was having issues with that inheriting form ActiveRecord.